# google-calendar sinon stub doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-calendar-api, sinon, stubbing

In my `calendar.spec.js`, I have:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const googleCalendar = google.calendar('v3')
...
before(() => {
    sinon.stub(googleCalendar.calendarList, 'list').resolves({ data: true })
})

after(() => {
    googleCalendar.calendarList.list.restore()
})
```

In my `calendar.js`, I have:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const googleCalendar = google.calendar('v3')
let { data } = await googleCalendar.calendarList.list({
  auth: oauth2Client
})
```

But it doesn't appear to be stubbed. It goes ahead and tries to connect to Google Calendar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From your code I can see that `googleCalendar` is a local variable, so if you create it in the spec file, it's not the same instance as in the calendar.js file..

Comment: So how can I better organize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the entire `googleapis` module with [`mock-require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require).

```js
const mock = require('mock-require');

mock('googleapis', {
  google: {
    calendar: () => ({
      calendarList: {
        list: () => {
          return Promise.resolve({
            data: {
              foo: 'bar'
            }
          });
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Once you mocked it, your module will consume the mocked module instead of the original so you can test it. So if you module is exposing a method that calls the API, something like that:

```js
exports.init = async () => {
  const { google } = require('googleapis');
  const googleCalendar = google.calendar('v3');
  let { data } = await googleCalendar.calendarList.list({
    auth: 'auth'
  });

  return data;
}
```

The test will be

```js
describe('test', () => {
  it('should call the api and console the output', async () => {
    const result = await init();
    assert.isTrue(result.foo === 'bar');
  });
});
```

Here is a small repo to play with it: https://github.com/moshfeu/mock-google-apis